# Error when Importing TypeScript Files from External Module in Next.js Project

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, next.js, build

I'm facing an issue in my Next.js project where I have the following project structure:

```
├── modules/
│   └── auth/
│       ├── index.ts
│       ├── page.tsx
│       └── package.json
└── nextjs-project/
    ├── ...
    └── package.json
```

In my Next.js project, I have a `tsconfig.json` file as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "my-auth-module": ["../modules/auth/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

In my module (e.g., `auth`), I haven't configured any webpack loader. However, when I try to import a page from the `auth` module in my Next.js project, I encounter the following error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:24)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type; currently, no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> import NextAuth, { type NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
```

Is there a way to load `.ts` / `.tsx` files without rebuilding them every time I make changes in the `modules` folder?

Comment: By default, webpack will not transpile your dependencies. Specify loader configuration in order to apply a transpiling loader to any dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, I think I found the solution: you need to use the Next config [transpilePackages](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/transpilePackages).

In your case, something like the following in your `nextjs-project/next.config.js` should do the trick:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  transpilePackages: ['my-auth-module'], //  

  /* the rest of your config ... */
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

By default Next doesn't transpile and/or bundle dependencies, you have to list them explicitly in your next config.